# Apache two domains on two different ip addresses

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am trying to setup up two different domains on two different ip addresses: bbb.zzz.xxx.yyy
 & bbb.xxx.yyy.zzz . Problem is, domain1 is working fine. Second site (domain2) is working when I enter ip address in the browser, but it shows content of domain1 when I enter wwww.domain2.com . How should I solve this ? Is there any module missing ? I am using different files in sites-available directory for different domains.

```
<VirtualHost bbb.zzz.xxx.yyy>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
  ServerAdmin **********@gmail.com
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com

  # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
  DirectoryIndex  index.php
  DocumentRoot /home/ApacheWebsites/domain1/httpdocs

  # Custom log file locations
  LogLevel warn
  ErrorLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/error.log


 CustomLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/access.log combined


    <Directory /home/ApacheWebsites/domain1/httpdocs/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
           Require all granted
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

```
<VirtualHost bbb.xxx.yyy.zzz>
  # Admin email, Server Name (domain name) and any aliases
      ServerAdmin ************@gmail.com
      ServerName domain2.com
      ServerAlias www.domain2.com

      # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex  index.php
      DocumentRoot /home/ApacheWebsites/domain2

      # Custom log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /home/ApacheWebsites/logs/access.log combined
        <Directory /home/ApacheWebsites/domain2/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
               Require all granted
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet says

```
ServerName domain1.com
ServerAlias www.domain2.com
```

Change the server alias to www.domain1.com and it should work.

Comment: oh no sorry it resolves to the ipaddress assigned to the domain1

Comment: change it and test it again ;)

Comment: its not working. www.domain2.com still loads content of domain1 (not when I use ip address directly). is there any module that I need to enable ?

Comment: You could try to define both virtual hosts by <VirtualHost *:80>. This ignores the incoming ip address and matches your domains to both hosts.